# How to kill a particular process in Linux?

Tags: linux, process, grep, kill

I would like to kill a particular process (it is a program which name is test.exe) in Linux. To do that I can type:

```
ps aux | grep test.exe
```

And then:

```
kill -9 process_id_of_test_exe
```

As You can see I need to type commands several times (not immediately). The question is how to do that in one command. Take the process_id of test.exe and give to kill. I think that I need to write a script in such case. Thanks.

Comment: pkill -f test.exe . This will match keyword test.exe and kill it.

Comment: @SrikanthJeeva `pkill` is not on my `ubuntu`

Comment: Its not two commands, its three. `ps` `grep` `kill`

Answer (score 3):

Use this command to get PID

```
pidof test.exe
1044
```

Then to kill it:

```
kill 1044
```

And then join them:

```
kill $(pidof test.exe)
```

You can also use your command:

```
kill -9 $(ps aux | grep [t]est.exe)
```

The `[t]` prevents `grep` from grepping itself.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

`killall test.exe`

See `man killall` for more details!

Answer (score 0):

You can combine kill -9  with pgrep like follows:

kill -9 `pgrep test.exe`

Answer (score 0):

For killing all processess with keyword `test.exe`, try

`pkill -9 -f test.exe`